# Matplotlib marker filled with 2 colors at specific ratios

Tags: python, matplotlib, styles, visualization, fill

I have a scatterplot on which I would like to add a dimension by the filling the markers by a certain amount, representing a percentage, as sketched:[image: Sketch]

I found how to fill markers [with 2 colors but only 50%/50%](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/examples/pylab_examples/filledmarker_demo.html) But not how to specify the ratio of each color.

Another option is to make [scatterplots of pie charts](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/scatter_piecharts.html), but I find it challenging with my scatterplot created from a dataFrame...

Here is what I have so far:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,7))

for region in df.regions:
    row = df[df.regions==region]

    row.plot.scatter(x=df.X,y=df.Y,
                    color = colors[str(region)],
                    s = row.SIZE.sum(),
                    ax=fig.gca())
```

[image: Looking like]

Comment: Are you asking how to create a scatterplot of pie charts or how to produce a plot like the sketched one?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ideally, how to produce a plot like the sketched one. If too complicated, alternatively how to make a scatterplot of pie chart with my data structure (dataframe) :)

Comment: Thinking about it, there isn't much of a difference between the two cases. You need 2 markers for each scatter point. The example pretty much shows how to do it; if trying cut circles, you may in addition need the formula that tells you the "waterlevel" in the circle from a given fraction (which is more a math question).

Comment: I'll follow up with this, thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest !

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, 
I have tried with the [scatterplots of pie charts example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/scatter_piecharts.html), but unsuccessfully: it results in very weird shapes for several points.

I am trying the "waterlevel" appraoch with markers = (numsides, style, angle) but am really struggling to get anywhere. Would you have any recommendation?

Thank you so much!

Comment: maybe you can come up with a [mcve] of what you have tried?

Comment: @Charlotte Did you solve this? Could you please post how you did it? Thanks